# Proof of Corollary to Theorem 1.25 in Shafarevich Basic Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The corollary to the Theorem on the Dimension of Fibres (Theorem 1.25) in Shafarevich Basic Algebraic Geometry is

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible quasiprojective varieties and $f: X \to Y$ be surjective and regular. Then the sets $Y_k = \{y \in Y | \dim f^{-1}(y) \geq k\}$ are closed in $Y$.

> Proof: Let $n = \dim X$ and $m = \dim Y$. By the Theorem on the Dimension of Fibres $Y_{n-m} = Y$, and there exists a closed subset $Y' \subsetneq Y$ with $Y_k \subseteq Y'$ if $k > n-m$. If $Z_i$ are the irreducible components of $Y'$ and $f_i: f^{-1}(Z_i) \to Z_i$ the restrictions of $f$, then $\dim Z_i < \dim Y$, and we can prove the corollary by induction on $\dim Y$. The corollary is proved.

Why does the induction work?

It is clear that $\dim Z_i < \dim Y$ since otherwise $\dim Z_i = \dim Y$ and since $Y$ is irreducible and $Z_i \subseteq Y$ closed, it would be $Z_i = Y$, a contradiction to $Y' \neq Y$. Surjectivity of $f_i$ is also clear, and that $Y_k = \bigcup_{i} Z_{i,k}$ for $k > n-m$, so $Y_k$ would be closed.

But doesn't $f^{-1}(Z_i)$ have to be irreducible too to use the Theorem on the Dimension of Fibres?

The Theorem on the Dimension of Fibres is:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be regular map between irreducible quasiprojective varieties. Suppose that $f$ is surjective, and that $\dim X =n$ and $\dim Y = m$. Then $m \leq n$ and (i) $\dim F \geq n-m$ for any $y \in Y$ and for any component $F$ of the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$; (ii) there exists a nonempty open subset $U \subseteq Y$ such that $\dim f^{-1}(y) = n -m$ for $y \in U$.

Comment: You're using a theorem here but not providing it. Please fix that by adding the theorem to your post with an [edit].

Comment: @KReiser I added the theorem